# creating certificate programmatically using cert authority

Tags: x509certificate

One of my company servers running Windows 2000 is hosting a Certificate Authority (microsoft based). When I open a web browser and type in http://server_name/certsrv, I get a page (titled Microsoft Certificate services) which allows me create a certificate request to this CA and get back a certificate which I then install in the certstore of the local PC.

I wish to to do this programmatically using C# because I need to generate a large number of certificates.

I have little idea what API I am looking for.

Any advice will be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already discovered, judging by your more recent questions, you can use `System.Security.Cryptography` and `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` namespaces from standard .NET framework and also open source [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) library. These are the API's you are looking for. Alternatively, you can use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) and invoke it from your .NET code, but I'd stick to pure .net solution.

Comment: These namespaces were my first choice but I was able to get some sample code on creating a CSR using the Bouncy Castle library. As you said, I was thinking of OpenSSL but I want to stick to pure .NET instead of calling into unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information on your requirements?

Things like: Where are the private keys going to be generated?  Will you be using a CSR from a remote host?  What kind of output are you wanting:

For instance, will you be generating PKCS12 files holding both the private and the public portion, or only outputting the public and holding the private somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I will be generating PKCS12 files with the private and public portion. My CSR will contain a flag to mark the private keys as exportable so that I can generate a PFX file once the certificate is issued.